# Read a txt file in python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5

I want to read line by line a txt file and save it to a list, my python version is 2.5, but I get syntax error, can you help me? 
My code is as follows:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 5):

context managers were introduced in python 2.6 ([PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)). In python 2.5 you have to do:

```
f = open("test.txt")
content = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
```

the main drawback is that you have to remember to close the file

another possibility (maybe even better) is to use `__future__` (make it the first line of your script):

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

then you're good to use `with` in python 2.5

Comment: `with` is officially part of Python 2.6, you have to import it from \_\_future\_\_ before using contextlib in Python 2.5.

Comment: @digitaLink that's true! thanks for pointing that out. Edited.